# simple aggregation using elasticsearch

Tags: elasticsearch

i am using elastic search to perform aggregation for hourly data and which is aggregated on basis of weekday name:
sample data:

```
{ val:40, hour:00, day:Monday   }
{ val:10, hour:01, day:Tuesday  }
{ val:30, hour:02, day:Wednesday}
{ val:40, hour:03, day:Thursday }
{ val:60, hour:04, day:Friday   }
{ val:70, hour:05, day:Saturday }
```

what mapping should i use so i can aggregate over `hour` field and then over `day` field. and what query should i use . is there anything inbuilt like `date_histogram`. i can normally aggregate over hour and day field but then the results are not sorted by hour and weekday and sorting it using elastic or in program would be costly. so i was thinking maybe something like `date_histogram` where by default dates are sorted.
**EDIT : i want result something like this:**

```
{
   Monday :{
     '01':{value:''}
     '02':{value:''}
     '03':{value:''}
     '04':{value:''}
 },
 Tuesday :{
     '01':{value:''}
     '02':{value:''}
     '03':{value:''}
     '04':{value:''}

}}
```

Comment: A bit incomplete / confusing question as of using date_historigram as you mentioned as it can only be applied on date values. Can you share a bit more context. Your index mapping would be a good start.

Comment: I have updated the question for some context . what mapping should i use and what quey that is my exact doubt